# Google Colab TensorFlow 'DistributedDatasetInterface' Error

Tags: python, tensorflow, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory, attributeerror

Found a solution.

Uninstalled the lastest version of tensorflow and reverted to a previous model

```
# Uninstall the current version of TensorFlow.
!pip uninstall tensorflow -2.13.0

# Install TensorFlow 1.15.0.
!pip install tensorflow==2.12.0

# Verify the TensorFlow version.
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```

Using Google Colab. This is the error when I ran model.fit(x,y).

**AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.distribute.input_lib' has no attribute 'DistributedDatasetInterface'**

I had read that it relates to compatibility issues between 'keras' and 'tensorflow' and a way to fix was to update tensor flow in google colab with

```
!pip install -U tensorflow
```

I did this and my tensorflow version is now 2.13.0 , but that didn't fix the issue.

These are my libraries

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

from tensorflow.python.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.python.keras.activations import linear
from tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers import adam_v2
```

Sequence was

1. Loaded the csv file, extracted the data and reshaped.
2. Used sklearn train_test_split() to create training, validation and test sets
3. Used **tf.keras.layers.Normalization(axis=-1, mean=None, variance=None)** to normalise all the x_train, x_validation, x_test data
4. Run the model

```
    [
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(input_shape=(30,), units=15, activation='relu',
                              name='L1'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(input_shape=(15,), units=10, activation='relu',
                              name='L2'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(input_shape=(10,), units=1, activation='linear',
                              name='L3'),
    ]  , name="My_Model"
)

opt = adam_v2.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()
model.compile(
    loss = loss,
    optimizer = opt,
)

model.fit(xn_train, y_train, epochs=100)
```

It is the **model.fit()** portion that has the error.

a. So I ensured that the inputs (xn_train, y_train) were both <class 'numpy.ndarray'>. That did not fix it

b. Then ensured but inputs were both <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor'>. That did not fix it either

Help please to fix this.

Comment: Would you please show detail source code in context?

Answer (score 0):

tensorflow/python/keras is legacy code. Remove it and use tf.keras instead.

The example below works for me.

```
import tensorflow as tf

Input = tf.keras.layers.Input
Dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense
Activation = tf.keras.layers.Activation
Dropout = tf.keras.layers.Dropout
Model = tf.keras.models.Model

input_layer = Input(shape=(X.shape[1],))
dense_layer_1 = Dense(15, activation='relu')(input_layer)
dense_layer_2 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(dense_layer_1)
output = Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax')(dense_layer_2)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics='acc'])

print(model.summary())

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=8, epochs=50, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)
```

or

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model

input_layer = Input(shape=(X.shape[1],))
dense_layer_1 = Dense(15, activation='relu')(input_layer)
dense_layer_2 = Dense(10, activation='relu')(dense_layer_1)
output = Dense(y.shape[1], activation='softmax')(dense_layer_2)

model = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['acc'])

print(model.summary())

history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=8, epochs=50, verbose=1, validation_split=0.2)
```